# PersistGate stuck on loading when query parameter present in URL

Tags: react-redux, local-storage, next.js

I'm using the example with-redux-persist repo paired with next.js found here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-persist

When using a custom loading component, adding a query parameter to the URL, ie `?test=123`, causes the page to hang on loading indefinitely. There are no errors reported in console and the redux state info looks clean.

Here is my `_app.js` I'm using to test this:

```
import { useStore } from '../store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState)
  const persistor = persistStore(store)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<div>Loading</div>} persistor={persistor}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

You can reproduce it by cloning the above repo, modifying `_app.js` to look like above, starting the server with yarn dev and then finally visiting `http://localhost:3000/?test=123`.

Any help or insight into why this is occurring is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issues for weeks. After take a look into nextjs github issues, I found the solution. Change your code to

```
import { useStore } from '../store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState)
  // here is the change
  const persistor = persistStore(store, {}, function () {
    persistor.persist()
  })

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<div>Loading</div>} persistor={persistor}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

This is the root cause:

> This PR is to fix "[Examples] Problem with query parameters in with-redux-persist (#15484)"
> The root cause is
> persist/rehydrate action will issue twice when query parameter is set. But persistStore initial bootstrap is not ready yet. So i add a bootstrap callback and force persistor to persist again to make overall state correct. I also modify the loading prop to a loading because it's confuse to set Component in loading prop.

Reference: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/16085